# Hyperlink the output result get from google sheet to Web app via Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

The idea is very simple: if we have 2 columns 'Passcode' and 'Url' in google sheet, then we use google app script to deploy a webapp to input password, if input matchs with the Passcode column, it returns the value of corresponding URL.

The problem is after hyperlink the result value by itself, when i click on the Hyperlinked text, it return **weird address** like this:

https://n-ccxp7zryfzliwrfqnp5cqe6fz2xj5be3d6vsvpq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/google.com

I have tried many way but still cannot find out the solution.

[Form HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vej06.png)

[The result when i click on hyperlinked text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvkQN.png)

The gsheet file with code in extension, you can create a copy for test deploy.
[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YMVnYY9NoDqhaPboUa2RnfUarSrbNJ_iRVZYMc7EwLQ/edit#gid=0)

**Here is my GS code:**

```
function getPasswordURL(password) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === password) {
      return data[i][1];
    }
  }
  
  return "URL not found";
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function getPasswordURL(password) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === password) {
      return data[i][1];
    }
  }
  
  return "URL not found";
}
```

**And here is index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="passwordForm">
      <label for="password">Enter Password:</label>
      <input type="text" id="password" name="password" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script>
      document.getElementById("passwordForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateResult).getPasswordURL(password);
      });

      function updateResult(url) {
        var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
        var domain = extractDomain(url);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = "#";
        link.textContent = domain;
        link.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          openNewTab(url);
        });
        resultDiv.innerHTML = "";
        resultDiv.appendChild(link);
      }

      function extractDomain(url) {
        var domain;
        // Find and remove the protocol (e.g., "http://" or "https://")
        if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {
          domain = url.split('/')[2];
        } else {
          domain = url.split('/')[0];
        }
        // Find and remove the port number
        domain = domain.split(':')[0];
        // Remove www. if present
        domain = domain.replace("www.", "");
        return domain;
      }

      function openNewTab(url) {
        var baseUrl = url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/[^/]+)\/.*$/, "$1");
        var newTab = window.open(baseUrl, '_blank');
        newTab.focus();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much for any helps from the experts on platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification poonts:

- When I saw your provided Spreadsheet and your current script, I noticed that there are 2 same function names of `getPasswordURL`. In this case, please remove one of them. Please be careful about this.
- From your provided Spreadsheet, for example, the cell "B2" has the text of `google.com` and the hyperlink of `http://google.com/`. But, in your script, only the cell value of `google.com` is retrieved by `getValues`. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your Google Apps Script is modified. Please modify your Google Apps Script as follows.

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function getPasswordURL(password) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getRichTextValues().map(([a, b]) => [a.getText(), b.getLinkUrl() || null]);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === password) {
      return data[i][1];
    }
  }
  return "URL not found";
}
```

- When this modified script is used in your provided Spreadsheet, "finance" is inputted into the text box and click "Submit" button, and when a link is clicked, the site is opened.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- This modification is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet, this modified script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank you, i am appreciated so much for your detailed explains and notes. This is just all i need. Have a nice day sir.